# Is it possible to create a user group via ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I am working on IaC in Azure. I need to create a user group via ARM template. Is it possible to accomplish this task in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has change recently, no. You can use the MS Graph API. You can set up PowerShell Scripts to run. Etc. And if you need this as part of the pipeline, there is likely a plug in on [marketplace, if keyed on pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Installs).

But I am trying to understand the need for creating a new group as part of the IaC. Is this because you need it configurable for different types of installs through pipelines? In general, I don't mix security with infrastructure unless I am making a product for others to install, so just trying to make sure you are not heading down a bad road.Do you mean resource groups instead?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I need to create a group with a role attached.  The role should provide any of the group members the ability to read azure sentinel alerts, issue queries, etc.

Comment: So, what is the purpose of setting it up with deploy? Is this a commercial product that you sell?

Comment: I am working with someone who is developing a commercial product for monitoring cloud environment. Thanks again for your answer!